# Primeng Button not showing label

Tags: angular, primeng

I have primeng button in my angular4 application.

label  of the button is not displaying.Button is displaying very small without label.

```
<div id="main">
  <form #newJobCleanUpForm="exForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(exampleForm)">

    <label class="stylelabel" for="jobNumber"><span>Job Number</span>
      <input  type="text" pInputText  class="styletext" id="jobNumber" required  [(ngModel)]="jobNumber" name="jobNumber">
      <button pButton type="button"  label="Click"></button></label>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but still its not working

Comment: Yes i removed that and it was not working . Instead I tried this <button pButton type="button">Click</button> and it is working

Comment: I think the HTML button is working, but ***PrimeNG*** pButton is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form i have a primeng text area and forgot to add name attribute to the text area. Primeng buttons were not displaying because of this. I corrected this mistake and everything works fine.

Comment: The reason why this works, is because it is a normal non-PrimeNG button. A normal HTML button does not know about the label-attribute, but it does display the child content. (Using a normal button is fine, if you don't need the features of the PrimeNG-button).

Comment: yes.PrimeNG button is not working even after importing ButtonModule

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by a missing import of PrimeNG's ButtonModule.

Please add this import to the same module, your component is defined in.

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

...

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      ...
      ButtonModule
   ]
   ...
```

Comment: thanks the advice "to the same module, your component is defined in" fixed it for me