# PrimeNG button not displaying fa icon and label in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to display Add and Delete button in the panel header. Below code displays button with no fa-icon and no label

```
<p-panel>
  <p-header>
   <div>
     Registration Form
     <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right" label="Add">
     </button>
   </div>
  </p-header>
</p-panel>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primeng Button not showing label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305915/primeng-button-not-showing-label)

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After importing the BrowserAnimationsModule , primeng Buttons are displaying inside the panel.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Answer (score 16):

Your code is working fine [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uXuMNeZyDOhSH5RIw5zH?p=preview).

Have you imported `font-awesome` to your application? If not, add this in your `index.html` within the `<head></head>` tag.

```
<head> 
...
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
```

Also, you will need to import `ButtonModule, PanelModule` to your application.

```
import {ButtonModule, PanelModule} from 'primeng';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    ...
    ButtonModule,
    PanelModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: You code is fine. It worked in my plunker. It has to be some sort of configuration problem. Do you see the panel on screen?

Comment: Yes i am able to see the panel with the header. Button is displaying blank.

Comment: Can you add your `app.module.ts` in your question please?

Comment: Added app.module.ts

Comment: I don't see the `import {ButtonModule, PanelModule} from 'primeng';` statement in your `app.module.ts`. I see them inside `imports` but they wont work without the import statement. Also, you mentioned in the question that pButton is working in `JobCleanupComponent`. Are you importing `primeng` modules in that component again?

Comment: Its there in the import statement import { DataTableModule , ButtonModule,DialogModule,InputTextareaModule,PanelModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng'; I am not importing anything in the JobCleanupComponent.

Comment: Thank you for importing `ButtonModule`

Answer (score 2):

if you are working with angular2/4 you'll need to add the following import to your app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Comment: yes but not necessarily app.module.ts - needs to be added to module in which it is being used - +1

Answer (score 0):

You have some structure errors in your example code.  I've created a plnkr for you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/myrBq9tv4iNRNd6v6bhT?p=preview

```
<p-panel>
  <p-header>
    <div>Registration Form
      <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right" label="Add"></button>
      <button type="button" class="ui-button-danger" pButton icon="fa-minus" style="float:right" label="Delete"></button>
    </div>
  </p-header>
</p-panel>
```

Comment: i corrected it.  But still icon and label is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from pi-close to fa-close worked for me.

Seems that there are new and old font awesome icons. They have to be used like this:

```
class="pi pi-xxx" or class="fa fa-xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use icon and label at the same time.Try below
`<button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" style="float:right"></button>`
and importing ButtonModule from primeng/button is a must